# How can I define a married couple in Clingo?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I'm trying to create 5 marriages, given 5 women and 5 man and their preferences to each other.

```
homem(miguel).
homem(joao).
homem(pedro).
homem(marco).
homem(carlos).

mulher(maria).
mulher(paula).
mulher(carla).
mulher(cristina).
mulher(ana).
```

all the marriages are stable (it is unstable if 2 person outside the marriage prefer each other more than their spouses), and I have their preferences to each other by ranks:

```
pref(miguel,paula,5).
pref(miguel,ana,4).
pref(miguel,maria,3).
pref(miguel,carla,2).
pref(miguel,cristina,1).

pref(maria,carlos,5).
pref(maria,miguel,4).
pref(maria,marco,3).
pref(maria,joao,2).
pref(maria,pedro,1).

pref(joao,maria,5).
pref(joao,paula,4).
pref(joao,carla,3).
pref(joao,cristina,2).
pref(joao,ana,1).

pref(paula,marco,5).
pref(paula,carlos,4).
pref(paula,joao,3).
pref(paula,miguel,2).
pref(paula,pedro,1).

pref(pedro,paula,5).
pref(pedro,carla,4).
pref(pedro,ana,3).
pref(pedro,cristina,2).
pref(pedro,maria,1).

pref(carla,miguel,5).
pref(carla,marco,4).
pref(carla,joao,3).
pref(carla,pedro,2).
pref(carla,carlos,1).

pref(marco,maria,5).
pref(marco,carla,4).
pref(marco,paula,3).
pref(marco,cristina,2).
pref(marco,ana,1).

pref(cristina,pedro,5).
pref(cristina,joao,4).
pref(cristina,marco,3).
pref(cristina,miguel,2).
pref(cristina,carlos,1).

pref(carlos,ana,5).
pref(carlos,carla,4).
pref(carlos,paula,3).
pref(carlos,maria,2).
pref(carlos,cristina,1).

pref(ana,marco,5).
pref(ana,joao,4).
pref(ana,pedro,3).
pref(ana,carlos,2).
pref(ana,miguel,1).
```

```
casamento(1..5). 

% every person belongs to one group only. 
1{in(H,M): casamento(C)}1 :- homem(H), mulher(M).

:- homem(H1), mulher(M1), homem(H2), mulher(M2), 
      pref(H1,M2,P1),pref(H1,M1,P2), P1>P2,
      pref(M2,H1,P3), pref(M2,H2,P4); P3>P4.
```

but this does not work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

The rule

```
1{in(H,M): casamento(C)}1 :- homem(H), mulher(M).
```

doesn't mean that "every person belongs to one group only", but that "every pair of man and woman belongs to exactly one marriage. This is equivalent to say that *every* man is married with *every* woman.

Instead, you should express the contrary: every marriage should "generate" exactly one pair of people:

```
1{in(H,M,C): homem(H), mulher(M)}1 :- casamento(C) .
```

But this doesn't prevent a men (or woman) to belong to two different marriages. So you shoul also add:

```
:- in(H,M1,C1), in(H,M2,C2), C1!=C2 .
:- in(H1,M,C1), in(H2,M,C2), C1!=C2 .
```

#### Problem 2

Moreover, in your constraint you're considering every pair of people (not every pair of *married* people!). So you should replace `homem(H1), mulher(M1), homem(H2), mulher(M2)` with `in(H1,M1,C1), in(H2,M2,C2)`.

#### Fixed code

```
casamento(1..5) .

1{in(H,M,C): homem(H), mulher(M)}1 :- casamento(C) .
:- in(H,M1,C1), in(H,M2,C2), C1!=C2 .
:- in(H1,M,C1), in(H2,M,C2), C1!=C2 .

:- in(H1,M1,C1), in(H2,M2,C2), 
   pref(H1,M2,P1), pref(H1,M1,P2), P1>P2,
   pref(M2,H1,P3), pref(M2,H2,P4), P3>P4 .
```

This program (plus the EDB in your example) generates the following marriages:

```
in(miguel,carla,2) in(marco,paula,3) in(joao,cristina,1) in(carlos,maria,4) in(pedro,ana,5)
```

#### Optional

If you don't want to hardcode the `5` and make it work for any number of people in input, you can dynamically count the number of women (or men, assuming that it's the same).

So you can replace `casamento(1..N).` with:

```
casamento(1..N) :- N = #count{ X : mulher(X) } .
```